# How to start a brand new process in Rails, without inherit current environment variables?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, environment-variables, subprocess, bundler

I'm developing an master rails app which controls other rails apps. It has a bash script to start those rails apps, and it works well while it's invoked in the command line manually.

But if I invoke it in the matter rails app, using `backticks`, `system`, or `exec`, the script will fail.

The error message is:
`unicorn_rails worker[0] -c ../configs/unicorns/c5.rb -E production must be run inside RAILS_ROOT:
 #<Gem::LoadError: can't activate rack (~> 1.0.0, runtime), already activated rack-1.2.1.
 Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.>`

And here is the bash file:
`cp configs/Gemfile* $1
cd $1
bundle
bundle exec unicorn_rails -c ../configs/unicorns/$1.rb -E production`

How to resolve a problem like this?

As you can see, I use `bundle exec` to start the child process, which should have it's own gems loaded, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The environment variables are passed by the OS to Ruby when it loads. Ruby adds its own additional variables, then starts Rails, which adds even more.

You should be able to manipulate them by playing with the ENV hash. This will display what is defined:

```
ENV.each { |key, val| puts "#{ key } => #{ val }"}
```

You can tweak what is passed to child processes by directly modifying the ENV values then invoking the code that starts the child:

```
ENV['PATH'] = '/path/to/application'
ENV['PATH'] # => "/path/to/application"
```

Modifying the path, or stripping unwanted ENV entries to limit a child app's knowledge of the environment is pretty common.

Comment: Won't that affects the running parent process?

Comment: It could, if you do it before the current running process has had a chance to parse ENV. If that is a concern then copy the current ENV, tweak it and spawn your child processes, then restore it. The child processes should have their own copy of the limited ENV at that point.

Comment: Cool, I found that you can simply `fork do {}` and change ENV in the `fork block` in ruby 1.9. Thank you!

Comment: Cool. Glad that got you where you needed to be.

Comment: By diff'ing the output the ENV variable in a Ruby 1.9.2 irb console and a rails 3.1.3 console using puts ENV.sort_by(&:first).map{|k,v| "#{k}: #{v}\n"} you can see that Rails adds BUNDLE_BIN_PATH, BUNDLE_GEMFILE and RUBYOPT env variables as well as adding the gem bin directory to the PATH env variable. Doesn't look like Ruby adds any vars to env itself. I wonder how much effort would it take to remove all the Rails and Ruby environment extras so that a subprocess could be completely cleaned invoked as if from a fresh UNIX shell. Is it just undefining these 3 env variables?